# How does Windows Terminal (preview) assign colors to files?

Tags: windows-10, terminal

I'm using the Windows Terminal (preview) to interact with the Linux subsystem. As far as I know, there is only one way of customizing the terminal, and this is through the `profile.json` configuration file. In particular, there is a list of colors you can modify for each profile. But, I'm interested to know how the terminal is assigning colors to the files. Does it go by their file extensions?

This came up because I see the following in my terminal, and it's a bit annoying to have different file extensions having the same colors, and files with the same extension having different colors. I wanted to report this as a bug on the official github site, but I first wanted to learn more about this. Any ideas?

Here, you will see that all my directories are colored the same (good). But, notice how the `.png` and `.py` files have inconsistent coloring (bad)!

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the terminal you can configure your exact preferred shade of blue, green etc. But it's not the terminal that decides when to use these colors, it's the tool you're executing. Is it `dir` from Cmd, or `dir`/`ls` of PowerShell, or `ls` of a Linux system?

Comment: The picture above is from issuing `ls` in the Ubuntu shell of the Windows Terminal (preview). Are you saying this sort of thing gets categorized in my `.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, look for `LS_COLORS` in `ls`'s manual page, as well as shell initialization files (under `/etc` and in your home, e.g. `.profile` and `.bashrc`) that might set this variable.

Comment: Hmm, `LS_COLORS` doesn't seem to be behaving properly in this terminal. I had played around with this in the past, and the issue is still present. In particular, `LS_COLORS="di=1;30" ; export LS_COLORS` doesn't change the color of directories. The only flag I was able to get working was the `ow` flag of `LS_COLORS`. If you get it working, could you post a working example?

Comment: "`LS_COLORS="di=1;30" ; export LS_COLORS` doesn't change the color of directories." – it works for me, although on a "real" Ubuntu, not in WSL.

Comment: Of course, it *should* work on Ubuntu. But, I'm working on WSL, and that's the focus of this question. I guess I should open a thread on the GitHub page about this.

Comment: Not sure which project's GitHub page you're thinking of. I think you should open another question here. This forum is for user questions, GitHub is for bugreports. It's unlikely that we're facing a bug here, much rather a lack of knowledge. And again: it's the `ls` utility that decides what to print in green, what to print in blue, what to print in purple. The terminal only decides the exact shade of these colors.

Comment: By the way, the seemingly inconsistent coloring is probably due to the executable bit which takes precedence over the file extension.

Comment: You are correct! I figured that recently.